# Manipulate retrieved ajax data in php

Tags: jquery, ajax

I made a basic ajax request to 2 variables. I want the values to be sent and manipulated in the back-end in order to use them in a database query. All that should happen on page load. My main.js code:

main.js file

```
var lat =  21.458965;
var lng =  -11.336985;
jQuery.ajax({
        type:"POST",  
        url: ajaxurl,                   
        data: {'action':'func',
               'lat':lat,
               'lng':lng}, 
        success:function(data){
                // note that i don't want the data to return back to the front-end.     
                        },
                        error:function(errorThrown){
                            console.log(errorThrown);
                        }
                    });
        }
```

functions.php

```
wp_register_script( 'main', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'js/main.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
wp_enqueue_script( 'main' );

function func(){
    if(isset($_REQUEST)){
            //i tried to retrieve using $_POST and $_GET but the 2 arrays where empty.
            // i need to retrieve  both vars and take them out of the function then use them in a db query.

    }
}
add_action('wp_ajax_func', 'func');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_func', 'func');
```

What i wanted here is to send data (2 int variables to be specific) from javascript file to functions.php so any other way to do that please tell me about it.

To do that i created a form with 2 hidden input elements using JS then submit it with $('form').submit(); but the page was loading twice(the normal page load and the submit reload).

Comment: Have a look at the changes. The ajax itself is not a problem, the problem is that i want the data sent to php and i don't want to send a response ... is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should use `die();` in ajax function call, but because you're not returning data and don't care what is returned it's not necessary

You should be using nonce, it's good practice to get used to always using it regardless of the situation.

http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces
http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

You should not be using a function called `func`, name it something specific to your setup, ie `process_my_lat_lng`

To solve the problem of the form being submitted twice, put the ajax call in a function and then call the function on page load:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    processMyLatLng();
});

function processMyLatLng() {
    var lat = 21.458965;
    var lng = -11.336985;
    jQuery.ajax( ajaxurl, {
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            'action': 'func',
            'lat': lat,
            'lng': lng
        },
        success: function(data) {
            // note that i don't want the data to return back to the front-end.
        },
        error: function(errorThrown) {
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when form (or other) data is submitted via AJAX, it can be accessed via the `$_POST` or `$_GET` variables depending on the method used. In your case, you are using the post method so you can access your 'lat' and 'lng' with `$_POST['lat']` and `$_POST['lng']` and manipulate them as needed.

Comment: and don't forget to either `die` or `exit` at the end of you AJAX handler function.

Comment: Thanks for your concern. I know about get and post but as i said all that happen on page load(ajax somehow act after page load)

Comment: Your question and the code samples you provide probably need to be revised then. I answered the question asked.